# navigating from one xaml page to another xaml page in silverlight 4?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I am new to silverlight. I want to go from login page to another page in silverlight 4. How to do that in silverlighr 4. Whats the code in c#?

I have written on login button click

```
NavigationService n = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(sender as Button);

n.Navigate(new Uri("SelectionPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService' does not contain a definition
for 'GetNavigationService'
```

I'm using System.windows.navigation namespace.

Comment: Is your project a Silverlight Navigation Application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

`this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("SelectionPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`

Answer (score 0):

I use your code in defining below manner but still it's not call that page
`this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Parchase_order_main.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`